# How to dismiss the progress bar

Tags: android

In my app there is a button that onClick moves you to a new activity with rss news.
I want to use a progress bar until the news are downloaded to the device...
I have make some tries but unfortunately the progress bar is starting until the rss load,when they present it stops but when i return to the previous activity with the android back button, the progress bar starts again and never stops..

I have entered the progress bar in the onClick of the button in my first activity:

```
Button nea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nea);
    nea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view) {


              Thread thread =  new Thread(null, null, "MagentoBackground");
                thread.start();
                m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(main.this,    
                      "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nea.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


        }  

    });
```

Where should I put something like `m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();`

Answer (score 0):

try out this way:
[how to open ProgressBar inside the alertDailog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856209/how-to-open-progressbar-inside-the-alertdailog/5857378#5857378)
or use Asynctask for that
[Issue with android layout and progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883537/issue-with-android-layout-and-progressbar/5884128#5884128)